# determmine image of $f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}\sqrt{x^2-1}$

$D_f={(-\infty,-1)}\cup {[1, +\infty)}$

How can i show algebraically that $$f\left( (1,+\infty) \right)=(0,1)$$

Indeed,

let $y\in \mathbb{R} $
$$
\begin{align}
 y\in f\left( ]1,+\infty[ \right) &\iff f(x)=y\\
 &\iff \dfrac{1}{x+1}\sqrt{x^2-1}=y\\
 &\iff  \sqrt{x^2-1}=yx+y\\
&\iff \begin{cases}
 |x^{2}-1|=y^{2}(x+1)^{2}&  \\
yx+y>0& \\
x> 1 &\\
\end{cases} \\
 &\iff \begin{cases}
 x-1=y^{2}(x+1)&  \\
y(x+1)>0& \\
x> 1 &
\end{cases}\\
 &\iff \begin{cases}
 x-y^{2}x=y^{2}+1&  \\
y(x+1)>0& \\
x> 1 &
\end{cases}\\
 &\iff \begin{cases}
 x=\dfrac{y^{2}+1}{1-y^{2}}&  \\
y(x+1)>0& \\
x> 1 &
\end{cases}\\
&\iff \dfrac{y^{2}+1}{1-y^{2}}>1
\end{align}$$

i'm trying to show that $y\in (0,1)$

I'm stuck here

Comment: For a *general* function, it may be very difficult to determine the image. This one presents relatively few problems, though.

Comment: we can use $h(x)=(f(x))^{2}$ such that $h(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for $x>1$

$$f(x)=\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x+1}}$$

we see that $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing at $(1,+\infty)$.

but

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=0$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=1$$

thus

$$f((1,+\infty))=(0,1)$$

> algebraically

let $x>1$

$$f(x)=y\implies 1-\frac{2}{1+x}=y^2$$
$$\implies x=\frac{2}{1-y^2}-1$$

- $$x>1\implies 0 <\frac{2}{1+x}<1\implies 0<y<1$$
- $$0<y<1\iff 0<1-y^2<1\implies \frac{1}{1-y^2}>1\implies x>1$$

Comment: this is Analytical Approach i'm looking  for algebric one

Comment: @Yacob Please look now.

Comment: how did you get that $f(x)=y\iff x=\frac{2}{1-y^2}-1$ please elaborate your steps

Comment: @Yacob And now, You see.

Comment: yes i see thank you

Comment: but w $x>1 \implies 0<y<1$ means $f((1,+\infty)\subset (0,1)$ right

Comment: $x>1\implies 0<f(x)<1$ means $f((1,+\infty))\subset (0,1)$.

Comment: شكرا أخي عبد الله على شرحك القيم من أي بلد أنت أنا من المغرب

Comment: @Yacob De rien mon ami du monde. Oui Morocco.